# Get mean and std from sfit object

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

After loading, a pre-fitted surface ([`sfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/sfit.html)) model is something like in the following figure.

**Question: How can I obtain the precise mean/std (not by tedious copying from the output) of x/y data from the sfit object?**

Remarks:

1. I am able to get all the coefficients by calling its [`coeffnames`/`coeffvalues`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/sfit.html) APIs. However it seems there's no similar API for the mean/std.
2. The original data that the sfit model is fit from is not accessible currently. So [the method](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/124034-get-mean-and-std-from-sfit-object) relying on the original data is not applicable.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of the `sfit` class, it turns out that the means and standard deviations are stored in `private` properties `meanx`, `meany`, `stdx`, `stdy`. The fact that these are `private` makes the job non-trivial, but [thanks to Yair Altman we know that](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-private-object-properties) calling `struct()` on a class usually reveals all its goodness.

Using the slightly modified example from the [`sfit` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/sfit.html),

```
x = 3 - 6 * rand( 49, 1 );
y = 3 - 6 * rand( 49, 1 );
z = peaks( x, y );
sf = fit( [x, y], z, 'poly32', 'normalize', 'on');
```

here's what we see:

```
>> sf

     Linear model Poly32:
     sf(x,y) = p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x^2 + p11*x*y + p02*y^2 + p30*x^3 + 
                    p21*x^2*y + p12*x*y^2
       where x is normalized by mean -0.3736 and std 1.887
       and where y is normalized by mean -0.04893 and std 1.644
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p00 =      0.4227  (-0.3731, 1.218)
       p10 =       1.764  (0.5627, 2.965)
       p01 =       1.313  (0.7715, 1.855)
       p20 =     -0.1054  (-0.6496, 0.4389)
       p11 =      0.4627  (0.03944, 0.8859)
       p02 =      0.1898  (-0.2443, 0.6239)
       p30 =     -0.6345  (-1.247, -0.02209)
       p21 =     -0.8263  (-1.32, -0.3327)
       p12 =     -0.4908  (-1.011, 0.02911)

>> sf_struct=struct(sf)
Warning: Calling STRUCT on an object prevents the object from hiding its implementation details and should thus be avoided. Use DISP or
DISPLAY to see the visible public details of an object. See 'help struct' for more information. 

    sf_struct = 

                 version: 2
            fCoeffValues: {[0.4227]  [1.7639]  [1.3130]  [-0.1054]  [0.4627]  [0.1898]  [-0.6345]  [-0.8263]  [-0.4908]}
             fProbValues: {1x0 cell}
                     sse: 59.5574
                     dfe: 40
                    rinv: [9x9 double]
            activebounds: [9x1 logical]
                   meanx: -0.3736
                   meany: -0.0489
                    stdx: 1.8875
                    stdy: 1.6441
                    xlim: [-2.8236 2.8090]
                    ylim: [-2.7585 2.6763]
                   fType: 'poly32'
               fTypename: 'Poly32'
               fCategory: 'library'
                    defn: 'p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x^2 + p11*x*y + p02*y^2 + p30*x^3 + p21*x^2*y + p12*x*y^2'
                  fFeval: 1
                    expr: @polySurface
                   Adefn: {}
                   Aexpr: {}
                  linear: 1
                 derexpr: @polySurfaceDerivative
                 intexpr: []
                    args: [11x3 char]
                 isEmpty: 0
                 numArgs: 11
               numCoeffs: 9
             assignCoeff: [1x234 char]
              assignData: ' x = FITTYPE_INPUTS_{10}; y = FITTYPE_INPUTS_{11};'
              assignProb: ''
                   indep: [2x1 char]
                   depen: 'z'
                   coeff: [9x3 char]
                    prob: ''
              fConstants: {[3]  [2]}
        fNonlinearcoeffs: []
             fFitoptions: [1x1 curvefit.llsqoptions]
                fStartpt: []

>> [sf_struct.meanx, sf_struct.meany, sf_struct.stdx, sf_struct.stdy]

    ans =

       -0.3736   -0.0489    1.8875    1.6441
```

At least in R2012b the above works.